# One set of security standards for IoT devices?

Tags: legal, iot

In a recent hearing in the House of Representatives [the question was asked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvId5-0295U&feature=youtu.be&t=2h3m00s) **whether it is feasible to create one set of security standards for all IoT devices**. One of the panellists said yes and the other two said no.

I was a bit puzzled by this. I would guess that it would be extremely difficult to have one standard for so many different types of products (refrigerators, cars, HVAC units, ...). I was wondering if someone familiar with the discussion could summarize the arguments for answering the question in the affirmative.

Comment: See Common Criteria, et al. In theory it provides a good baseline for things, but in practice it's useless because it doesn't provide a lot of tangible security benefits.

Comment: "the more you tighten your grasp the more systems will slip through your fingers"

Comment: No. Everything related to the internet is a kind of big polite agreement which the big players comply by. IoT and security are currently at opposite extremes.